# Why PHP register_shutdown_function returns no output on Chrome?

Tags: php, cloudflare

on our package, we depend on register_shutdown_function but it has come to our attention that this function causes an issue with some of our package users when trying to echo something from inside the function

```
echo 'Script loaded';

register_shutdown_function( "fatal_handler_fn" );

function fatal_handler_fn(){

    mail('test@gmail.com', ' execusion finished', ' Yes it finished');

    echo ' Script ended';

}
```

on chrome, it returns no output but we receive the email which means the function got executed

here is what Chrome returns

[image]

ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

on FireFox, the first part of the output got returned but the second part which is in the function was not returned

[image]

using cURL, the first part was returned + this error message

[image]

curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

So, it seems not to be a Chrome problem but stream closes without returning correct details or something

Tried to wrap the register function inside a try-catch block but no errors are triggered or logged

PHP version 7.2.20

Linux linux.adaletinsesi.com 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 16:35:19 UTC 2019 x86_64

CDN: CloudFlare